# Apache sites not working after upgrdaded to 2.4

Tags: linux, apache, virtualhost, apache2.4

I recently upgraded my `apache` from 2.2 to 2.4. After the upgrade, my virtual hosts and `localhost` aren't working from any other computers on the local network. It works only from the local computer where apache installed. This is the configuration from `apache2.conf`

```
<Directory />
    Options FollowSymLinks
    AllowOverride None
    Require all denied
</Directory>

<Directory /usr/share>
    AllowOverride None
    Require all granted
</Directory>

<Directory /var/www/>
    Options Indexes FollowSymLinks
    AllowOverride All
    Require all granted
</Directory>
```

In my virtual hosts, I've `Require all granted`. So it should work, I verified the machine with IP, ping works fine. So clearly, its something related to the apache only. Am I missing any other steps for the migration?

Comment: So you *only* upgraded apache, or also any other components of your linux box?

Comment: All the components I upgraded.

Comment: So ... which distro are you using, from which version to which version did you upgrade, and what does firewalling look like?

Comment: There is no firewall, its disabled. I installed some updates on ubuntu 20.04

Answer (score 1):

Check the `Listen` directive in `httpd.conf` probably you are listening only on `localhost`.

Comment: If I listen on localhost, if I hit the IP from the local network, it should work. But it doesn't

Comment: No, if you listen only on localhost and hit the IP from local network it shouldn't work.

Comment: I've `Listen 80`

Comment: Ok, you are listening on all interfaces. Do you have some error in you logs? Is your firewall up? Is it blocking something?

Comment: No firewall, its disabled. I see no access log and no error log

Comment: I suggest to backup your configuration, restart from clean one (for example the default config) and then add the modification step by step. In this way, you can find where apache stops to work the right way.

Comment: Ok, I'll try that